# why EF tries to add new record instead of edit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have the following code:

```
        var currentUser = (from i in _dbContext.Users
                           where i.FirstName == user.FirstName && i.LastName == user.LastName
                               && i.Title == user.Title && i.Company == user.Company
                           select i).FirstOrDefault();

                        currentUser.Company = user.Company;
                        currentUser.CompanyUrl = user.CompanyUrl;
                        currentUser.Country = user.Country;

                        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

but I got an error

> {"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_Users'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (a8,
>   b8, c8).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

so, it says that EF tries to add new record instead of edit current. Why?

Comment: public void RegisterUser(User user, string username, string password)
        {/* this code */} and then call this method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem will be combining `user` and `currentUser`. It most probably updates your `currentUser` but in the same time inserts `user`. The reason can be this:

```
currentUser.Company = user.Company;
```

If company has Users navigation property and if you are using POCO template this will connect both `Company` and `user` as new entities to the context.

Try this:

```
var currentUser = ...;

var company = new Company { Id = user.Company.Id };
_dbContext.Companies.Attach(company);

currentUser.Company = company;
...

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: hm, probably yes. But why and how to check?

Comment: You must not combine detached entities with attached. EF doesn't allow entity graph consisting from detached and attached entities. If you have detached `user` you cannot assign its detached `Company` to attached `currentUser`. It will make all three entities attached and saved.

Comment: yes, problem was in it. But really can't understand. I created user as new User(), it was not attached to _dbContent.Also, all those 3 fields were strings.